# Execute route only when direct component is called

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I want to unzip files whenever a "direct" route is called. The fileName I am getting from some other direct route.

```
from("direct:unZipFile")
                .from("file:C:\\MYFILES\\File\\Unzipped\\?fileName=${header.fileName}&idempotent=true")
                .split(new ZipSplitter())
                .streaming()
                .to("file:C:\\MYFILES\\File\\Unzipped\\")
                .split(body().convertToString().tokenize("\n"))
                .transform()
                .simple("${in.body}")
                .end();
```

Now it is working when I call the direct component but it also keeps on scanning the directory and processes the same file. I understand that the above code allows the trigger from direct as well as file component but I just want it to execute from "direct" component and I can't remove the "file" component as from that only I am reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to use pollenrich

```
from("direct:unZipFile")
.pollEnrich.simple("file:C:\\MYFILES\\File\\Unzipped\\?fileName=${header.fileName}")
.split(new ZipSplitter())
.streaming()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use consumerTemplate

```
from("direct:unZipFile")
                .process(exchange -> { 
                    Exchange recvFiles = exchange.getContext().createConsumerTemplate().receive("file:C:\\MYFILES\\File\\Unzipped\\?fileName=${header.fileName}&idempotent=true");
exchange.getIn().setBody(recvFiles.getIn().getBody());
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().putAll(recvFiles.getIn().getHeaders());
})
                .split(new ZipSplitter())
                .streaming()
                .to("file:C:\\MYFILES\\File\\Unzipped\\")
                .split(body().convertToString().tokenize("\n"))
                .transform()
                .simple("${in.body}")
                .end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just set the message body with a `java.io.File` where you compute the file name in a few lines of Java code, but yeah otherwise the pollEnrich is the EIP pattern solution for this.